# What are the implications of having weak A or B blood?

Tags: blood, blood-donation, blood-type

I have a child with weak B blood. I figured out that this means that the B antigen is only weakly expressed: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2267/

So I understand what this is, but my confusion is what are the implications  for blood donation and blood transfusion? Can anyone help clarify this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article [The importance of weak ABO subgroups](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Karan_Saluja/publication/246757334_Importance_of_Weak_ABO_Subgroups/links/53d549300cf2a7fbb2ea57da.pdf) has a section on this, in addition to general information on what weak subgroups are. All quotes in this answer areas from that study.

*Weak blood types*

Weak blood types can be caused by a person having a mutation that leads to not expressing the type A or B antibodies as much, or by mutations in the genes coding for these that mean the antibodies they do produce react less when brought into contact with type A and B antigens for testing.

> These weak phenotypes, in majority of the
>   cases result from the expression of an alternate weak allele present at the ABO loci.

Weak type A and B are different, and there are also [different weak subtypes for each](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8036794). For example, here is a case study of a patient with weak type A blood (much of the research is on that, as it is more common than weak type B): [A weak blood group A phenotype caused by a translation-initiator mutation in the ABO gene.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16533287)

*Blood donors*

Basically, weak type A or B blood donors's blood may be mistyped as being type O. If it is given to recipients with blood type O, these patients may experience blood agglutination which can be dangerous.

> Identification of these subgroups is important because these donors may be mistyped as group O individuals. Wrongly grouped as O, weak subgroups of A or B red cells (if transfused to O group individuals) can show decreased survival.

This does not concern your case, as it is about weak type A, but I'm including this for completeness sake: One of the weak type A groups, A<sub>x</sub> is special, in that people with this blood type should not donate for people with type A blood, as they actually have antibodies against the dominant type A antigen.

> Similarly since Ax individuals almost always have anti-A1 antibodies in their serum. If clinically significant, they can lead to fatal transfusion reactions on transfusing their whole blood or plasma to group A individuals.

*Blood recipients*

None of the sources I could find went into much detail what this meant for receiving blood transfusions. None mentioned not being able to receive type A or B blood if the patient is a weak type A or B.

Being mistyped as O when receiving blood is not going to lead to any major problems - however, it means the person will only receive type O blood and not type A or B blood. In situations with a donor blood shortage this might be a disadvantage.

The researchers of the study told the donors, so they would know that their blood could not be given to a type O patient.

> All the donors were personally informed about their group and were given a special blood group card clarifying their donor as well as recipient status.

You might want to give your child something similar to carry around with them. Maybe the doctor/lab that identified the weak blood type has something suiting.